# react native maps stopped working after running expo prebuild

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-maps

I needed to run the expo prebuild command in my project, due to the need for the notifee notifications library, the library in question worked normally, but the map library that I was also using (react native mps), stopped working. the map simply no longer appears in . does anyone know how to solve?

Comment: Can we see your code please ?

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution for this?
Im facing the same problem